# How to use str.replace() with a dictionary of replacements? Python

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

Given a dictionary of replacements, where `key = to be replaced` and `value = replacements`, e.g.:

```
replacements = {u'\u2014':'-', u'\u2019':"'", u'\u2018':"'", u'\u201d':'"', u'\u201c':'"'}
```

**How do i perform a replace without iterating through the `replacements.keys()`?**

**How will the same operation be possible with regex, `re.sub()`?**

I have been doing it this way:

```
for r in replacements:
  sentence = sentence.replace(r,replacements[r])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [`unicode.translate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) instead. It takes a mapping of unicode *ordinals* (integer numbers) and the values should be ordinals too, or unicode strings, or `None` to signal to delete that character:

```
replacements = {ord(k): ord(v) for k, v in replacements.iteritems()}
sentence = sentence.translate(replacements)
```

Demo:

```
>>> replacements = {ord(k): ord(v) for k, v in replacements.iteritems()}
>>> replacements
{8216: 39, 8217: 39, 8212: 45, 8221: 34, 8220: 34}
>>> u'\u2019Hello world! \u2014 You rock!\u2018'.translate(replacements)
u"'Hello world! - You rock!'"
```